# WCF Rest Service Reference in ASP.net core 3.1 API

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I've created a WCF Restful service(Framework 4.7.2) and hosted the service in IIS sever. I would like to add the service on a ASP.net core 3.1 Api. It does fails while adding it via connected service. The wcf service has endpoint with webhttpbinding.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUeS9.png)
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Core does not support webhttpbinding, wcf only supports BasicHttpBinding, CustomBinding, NetHttpBinding, NetTcpBinding：

[image]

So there are two current solutions:

**Modify the binding of the server, do not use webhttpbinding.**

**The client continues to use the .net framework.**

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.